# Only read functions when called - PHP

Tags: php, function

I have two functions, which take a parameter.

The way my script works is that it retrieves some data as a string. This string can be in two formats, which is unkown to me and cannot be obtained beforehand.

So i have 2 functions, one for each type of format.

Function 1 is first called, with the string passed as a parameter. I then check if a variable within this function has been assigned. If the variable has been assigned, it means the string format was recognised. If the variable has not been assigned, function 2 is then called with the same parameter. This should work.

The problem is that when I run the script, say if function1 works, then I get undefined variable errors for function 2. I don't understand why this is the case, as it has not been called yet and therefore should not have been processed/looked at.

Is there a way I can only make a function available when it is called?

```
recurrence_info_day($eventtype);
$recurrence_type = "daily";
if (!$eventstart){
   recurrence_info_weekly($eventtype);
   $recurrence_type = "weekly";
}

function recurrence_info_day($eventtype){
    $s = $eventtype;    
    preg_match('/^DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:(\d+)\s+DTEND;VALUE=DATE:(\d+)\s+RRULE:FREQ=(\w+);INTERVAL=(\d+);UNTIL=(\d+)/', $s, $recinfod);
    $eventstart = $recinfod[1];
    $eventend = $recinfod[2];
    $eventfrequency = $recinfod[3];
    $eventinterval = $recinfod[4];
    $eventuntil = $recinfod[5];

    $formstartdate = substr($eventstart,4,2)."/".substr($eventstart, 6)."/".substr($eventstart,0,4);
    $formenddate = substr($eventuntil,4,2)."/".substr($eventuntil, 6)."/".substr($eventuntil,0,4);
}

function recurrence_info_weekly($eventtype){
    $s = $eventtype;
    preg_match('/^DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:(\d+)\s+DTEND;VALUE=DATE:(\d+)\sRRULE:FREQ=(\w+);BYDAY=(\d+);UNTIL=(\d+)/', $s, $recinfow);
    $eventstart = $recinfow[1];
    $eventend = $recinfow[2];
    $eventfrequency = $recinfow[3];
    $eventdays = $recinfow[4];
    $eventuntil = $recinfow[5];

    $formstartdate = substr($eventstart,4,2)."/".substr($eventstart, 6)."/".substr($eventstart,0,4);
    $formenddate = substr($eventuntil,4,2)."/".substr($eventuntil, 6)."/".substr($eventuntil,0,4);
}
```

Comment: Please paste your exact errors.  Based on what is shown here I would think the undefined index is occuring on `if (!$eventstart){`, which is not inside function 2.

Comment: Also, `preg_match` returns a value. check it, before assuming it was successful.

Comment: Please give example strings for `$eventtype`. At least two, one matching for the first (day), and one for the second type (weekly).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your functions return *something* so that you know if they matched anything:

```
function myFunction() {
    return 'A';
}

$a = myFunction();
echo $a; # value;
```

Your function returns more than one value. So you can make it return multiple values, that can be done with an array:

```
function myFunction2() {
    return array('A', 'B');
}

list($a, $b) = myFunction2();
echo $a, ' ', $b; # A B;
```

Apart from these basics, you've got a lot of code-duplication in those two functions. They basically differ in the pattern you run with `preg_match`. So you can extract that part as a method of it's own (Refactoring -> Extract Method).

Doing that and actually checking return values from either your own and PHP's own functions could lead to that. Which isn't perfect but shows some improvement over your original code and allows you to actually test if some eventtype was triggered. Example:

```
$eventtype = 'DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:123456789 DTEND;VALUE=DATE:123456789 RRULE:FREQ=2;INTERVAL=2222;UNTIL=123456789';

$result = recurrence_info_day($eventtype);
if ($result) {
    $recurrence_type = "daily";
    list($event, $form) = $result;
} else {
    $result = recurrence_info_weekly($eventtype);
    if ($result) {
        $recurrence_type = "weekly";
        list($event, $form) = $result;
    }
}

var_dump($eventtype, $recurrence_type, $event, $form);


function recurrence_info_day($eventtype){
    $pattern = '/^DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:(\d+)\s+DTEND;VALUE=DATE:(\d+)\s+RRULE:FREQ=(\w+);INTERVAL=(\d+);UNTIL=(\d+)/';
    return reccurence_info_pattern($eventtype, $pattern);
}

function recurrence_info_weekly($eventtype){
    $pattern = '/^DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:(\d+)\s+DTEND;VALUE=DATE:(\d+)\sRRULE:FREQ=(\w+);BYDAY=(\d+);UNTIL=(\d+)/';
    return reccurence_info_pattern($eventtype, $pattern);
}

function reccurence_info_pattern($eventtype, $pattern)
{
    $r = preg_match(
        $pattern,
        $eventtype,
        $recinfow
    );

    if (!$r) {
        return NULL;
    }

    $event = new stdClass();
    $event->start = $recinfow[1];
    $event->end = $recinfow[2];
    $event->frequency = $recinfow[3];
    $event->days = $recinfow[4];
    $event->until = $recinfow[5];

    $form = new stdClass();
    $form->startdate = substr($event->start, 4, 2) . "/" . substr($event->start, 6) . "/" . substr($event->start, 0, 4);
    $form->enddate = substr($event->until, 4, 2) . "/" . substr($event->until, 6) . "/" . substr($event->until, 0, 4);
    return array($event, $form);
}
```

Output:

```
string(98) "DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:123456789 DTEND;VALUE=DATE:123456789 RRULE:FREQ=2;INTERVAL=2222;UNTIL=123456789"
string(5) "daily"
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
  ["start"]=>
  string(9) "123456789"
  ["end"]=>
  string(9) "123456789"
  ["frequency"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["days"]=>
  string(4) "2222"
  ["until"]=>
  string(9) "123456789"
}
object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
  ["startdate"]=>
  string(11) "56/789/1234"
  ["enddate"]=>
  string(11) "56/789/1234"
}
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest solution is to make the variables you need outside of the function global.
Put

```
global $eventstart, $eventend...
```

at the beginning of the function.

But really, the design is terrible. make the functions return a hash or null instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your conditional more carefully - the only way that function two is running is if $eventstart is set. Perhaps:

```
if ($eventstart == ""){}
```

This should stop the conditional from being triggered.
Another option would be set $eventstart to a specific condition at the end of the first function, and then look for that condition to run the second:

```
(within first function) if ($recinfod[1] ==""){$eventstart = FALSE};
```

Bests,